# Does a multi-step operation which needs to be reused belong in the fragment, the viewmodel, a repository, or another object/service?

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel

I have a simple process which needs to complete during initiation of the app (splash fragment/view model) but also needs to be run from another fragment (settings fragment/view model). It:

1. does an insert into a room table
2. waits for the resulting id
3. gets the new object from the database (so it has the createAt datetime)
4. sends the object to a webapi

I am struggling to understand where to put all this logic. My inclination is to do it in the view model as opposed to the fragment, so the fragment makes one call and all the work is done. Likely I will have to incorporate a listener into the view model so the fragment knows when everything is done, or if there is an error. Does this seem like the right place to put it?

If I do that, I have a different view model for the settings fragment. I don't want to recreate the logic for the splash view model. So how do I share this logic between the view models? Do I push it into the repository?

I'm using Java not Kotlin if that matters.

Comment: if it needs to be done in two fragments, obviously it won't work if you put it in a fragment, as the other one will need it too. viewmodels are lifecycle aware and provide other benefits too. there's no reason why you have to put all this code into _just one_ of these, you can split it between the VM and repo.

Comment: Thanks. I think this means some middle layer between ViewModel and Repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are definitely correct to not put it in a fragment, in modern Android development the Android lifecycle classes should always be kept as lean as possible.

Generally speaking, regardless of the architecture you are using, the viewmodel is still part of the view/presentation layer and shouldn't implement too much business logic if it can be avoided. Whereas a repository should have the single responsibility of storing, retrieving and updating a single model, but from multiple sources if necessary.

---

So in answer to your question, it depends. If all your steps 1-4 are referring to a single operation (which could be with multiple sources) concerning the same model then I would say that all of this logic should stay in the repository.

However if your steps include domain logic which concerns interacting with multiple models then I would recommend referring this work to your domain layer, maybe in the form of a use case or something similar. If this seems overkill for your application, then although it isn't best practice, letting a shared viewmodel (scoped to a parent fragment or activity) implement this logic would be acceptable.

Comment: So either Repo or a Domain layer, likely domain layer.

Comment: Well by the sounds of it, your process involves just persisting the same object locally and then remotely? If that's the case then it should be in the repository. The repositories job is to provide abstraction over data sources.